# Pronunciation of "genre" as "jarre"

Tags: prononciation

I noticed that some people from Saint Étienne tend to pronounce "*genre*" like "jarre". Are there other words with such pronunciation alteration in Saint Étienne and around?

Comment: Peux-tu préciser un peu ta question ? S'agit-il de la prononciation de la consonne /ʒ/ ou de la voyelle, la voyelle /ɑ̃ / étant normalement nasalisée mais que le français méridional (sous l'influence de l'occitan) a tendance à prononcer comme une voyelle orale /a/.

Comment: @Laure Prononciation de la consonne /ʒ/.

Comment: Le /ʒ/ en consonne d'attaque de ces deux mots est la prononciation normale. J'avoue que je n'ai jamais entendu autre chose, même en dehors de Saint-Étienne.

Comment: @Laure Sorry I didn't mean the consonne, but the voyelle /ɑ̃ /. Regarding the pronunciation of the first consonant in genre, I don't remember whether it was the same as in jarre.

Comment: Beaucoup de gens prononcent "genre" comme "jaure". Deux examples dans cette vidéo (à 35'' et 2'30''): http://www.jeuxvideo.com/videos/chroniques/869790/top-10-des-meilleurs-jeux-de-strategie-en-temps-reel.htm Très énervant...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add to Leni's answer, natives of Saint-Etienne and the Loire département often have a specific accent that sounds a bit like some Southern accents but with longer, more twisted /ɑ̃/ vowels among other differences.

You can have a taste of it [in this parody interview](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oIlcVPaZp40) of Loire-born former national football team coach Aimé Jacquet, although it might not be a 100% accurate reproduction.

Answer (score 2):

In the south, French people have the tendency to open their vowels much more. Another example would be "un bouquet de roses" : in the north and centre, we say something closer to "rôôôses", whereas in the south, you will almost hear "rases". It is just part of the southern accent.